# I am getting an error while running android studio ,also my haxm manager is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm, x86-emulation

Emulator: emulator:ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
[Here is the snapshot of haxm manager error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtpCg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator` from Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager.

Once downloaded, you need to install the package. But before installing in Windows, enable `VT-X (Intel Virtualization Technology (VT, VT-x))`

Comment: how to enable VT-X (Intel Virtualization Technology (VT, VT-x))?

Comment: i have already installed Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator ,but it is not runnning